# How to transform a list to a map of lists in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list :

```
field = ["key1.value1", "key1.value2", "key2.value3"]
```

that I want to transform into a `Map<String, List<String>>` such as

```
attributes = {"key1"=["value1", "value2"], "key2"=["value3"]}
```

The following works pretty well :

```kotlin
for (elem in field) {
    val key = elem.split(".").first()
    val value = elem.split(".").last()
    if (key in attributes.keys) attributes[key]!!.add(value)
    else {
        attributes[key] = mutableListOf()
        attributes[key]!!.add(value)
    }
}
```

but it's not very kotlin-like. I tried with `associateByTo`:

```kotlin
val attributes = mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>()
field.associateByTo(
        destination = attributes,
        keySelector = { it.split(".").first() },
        valueTransform = { mutableListOf(it.split(".").last()) }
)
```

but this only keeps the last value, as said in the doc. How can I build such a map in a kotlin way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without intermediate collections by using [groupBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) directly:

```kotlin
val attributes = field.groupBy({ it.substringBefore(".") }, { it.substringAfter(".") })
```

Or to make it slightly more readable to the uninitiated:

```kotlin
val attributes = field.groupBy(
    keySelector = { it.substringBefore(".") },
    valueTransform = { it.substringAfter(".") },
)
```

Comment: +1 for the substringBefore, and substringAfter. I went for standard array indices. `.groupBy( { it.split(".")[0] }, { it.split(".")[1] } )`

Comment: With `split()` + array indices you will create 2 new collections for every string in the initial list, which is kinda wasteful (although probably not a problem if the list is not unreasonably large).
Also, I find that `substringBefore/After` really reflect the intent here, better than `split()[0]`. We don't want to "extract a list of dot-separated elements and take the #0", we want to "take the part of that string that's before the dot".

Answer (score 2):

You need [groupBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) function

```kotlin
val result = field
    .map { it.split(".") }
    .groupBy({ it.first() }, { it.last() })
```

Comment: Goddamnit, i was 2 minutes late. The `let` though isn't really necessary. With it the `first()` and `last()` becomes function calls, but nothing else changes